# Update Data Method in C# for a SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I've just gotten started with creating a simple inventory extension for a web app and I've run into an issue where I'm having trouble updating the rows in a table for values that already exist in the `Product` column.

The method is pretty similar to the insert data method, which is working so I'm not exactly sure about what is going on. Here's the code that I have:

```
static void ReplaceInventory(string product, int qty)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
           "Data Source=TestSQL;Initial Catalog=TestInv;User ID=tester;Password=passwordtest;"))
    {
        con.Open();

        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                   "UPDATE Inventory SET Qty = @Qty WHERE Product = @Product", con))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qty", qty));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Product", product));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch  
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Record not updated");
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

This works however:

```
static void AddInventory(string product, int qty)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
           "Data Source=TestSQL;Initial Catalog=TestInv;User ID=tester;Password=passwordtest;"))
    {
        con.Open();

        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                   "INSERT INTO Inventory VALUES(@Product, @Qty)", con))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Product", product));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Qty", qty));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Count not insert.");
        }

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try to remove `@` symbol in `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qty", qty));` and `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Product", product));` so both lines have "Qty" and "Product" as query parameter names, you have it that way in INSERT query which works.

Comment: Is it throwing an exception?  What is the exception?

Comment: It isn't throwing an exception, which makes troubleshooting this maddening since I'm getting no message that would indicate a specific error. Removed the @ symbols, but it still is behaving this way.

Comment: You're passing in a `@product string` as the "key" to your product table. Are you absolutely sure that you got that right? Do you have a difference in spelling, or is there an extra space at the end of that string, either in your C# code or in the database? Strings as keys are a tricky business.....

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the same, I just checked the table on the server and the two columns in it are "Product" which is a "text" type column, and "Qty" which is an "int". The table was added programmatically-- the command was  
      "CREATE TABLE Inventory (Product TEXT, Qty INT)", 
     {
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the command type as Text, before executing the query:

```
command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
```

Comment: Added this before the command.parameter statements, no dice so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged your code and checked if the values are passed properly?

Try including the `SqlDbType` and size.

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Product",SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20,product);
```

For implicit conversion, try `AddWithValue`

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(new SqlParameter("@Qty", qty));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(new SqlParameter("@Product", product));
```

According to **MSDN**:

> AddWithValue replaces the SqlParameterCollection.Add method that takes
>   a String and an Object. The overload of Add that takes a string and an
>   object was deprecated because of possible ambiguity with the
>   SqlParameterCollection.Add overload that takes a String and a
>   SqlDbType enumeration value where passing an integer with the string
>   could be interpreted as being either the parameter value or the
>   corresponding SqlDbType value. Use AddWithValue whenever you want to
>   add a parameter by specifying its name and value.

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) for reference.

But using `command.Parameters.Add` is more reliable and safe because the type of the data is defined and the database doesn't need to identify and convert the data being sent.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Hi @marc_s , I know about it. Edited my answer for better purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The "Product" column in the table that I had created in my database was of a "text" data type, and so it wasn't recognizing the "=" as valid in the UPDATE expression. When I swapped the "=" sign out for LIKE the function worked as expected. Thanks for the feedback!